# Can I take the text of my own already published book (ebook & POD), amend & improve it, add new title and cover pic, and self-publish as a new book?

Tags: fiction, novel, publishing, copyright, self-publishing

I have a published (ebook & paperback) novel which was published in 2015 by a UK publishing house. The text was never carefully or properly proofed and there were many printing problems. Net result was a poor quality piece of work which appeared on various platforms and retail outlets, but never sold.
I have revised the text and improved it considerably, but it's still basically the same story. I have a new title and a better front cover, blurbs etc.Can I, as the same author with copyright, publish this new version under its new title, either through a different publisher, or through a self-publishing platform?

Comment: I would be very careful about this, you really should talk to the owner of the original material first, in case you want to sue yourself.  ...oh, wait... ? But seriously the only legal question here is if the terms of your agreement with the publisher allow it. And that has no generic answer; it boils down to the language of your contract.

Answer (score 2):

This entirely depends on the details of the contract.  If you signed an abusive contract, you may never be able to legally publish it again.  If you signed a good one but it's still in print, you probably don't have rights.

This is probably something a lawyer has to be consulted on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that you are the copyright owner of the work.
2. Carefully study the contract you have with the UK publisher. Is there a "reversion of rights" clause? Read it carefully.
3. Ask the publisher for a "reversion of rights" and see what they say. Remind them that the book "never sold."
4. If all fails, hire an intellectual property attorney to help you.